# Lua cut-scene - coroutine.resume leads to fps drop (or i doing it wrong)

Tags: lua

I try to use coroutines to achieve cut scenes using Lua, and there are no problems with that except massive fps drop.

I really don't know why, but coroutine.resume slow down my program like from 5000 fps (without any rendering at all) to 300-350 fps while event couroutine is not dead (e.g resume constantly). Then event became dead fps returns to normal.

I think couroutines can't be so slow, and there are problems in my event.lua/eventManager.lua code, or i measure fps wrong way, or i doing everything completely horrible.

Event.lua

```
function event()
    print("Event started")
    --simply as it can be
    for i = 1,1000 do
        coroutine.yield()
    end
    --[[ wait
    local wait = 0.0
    print("Waiting 5 sec")
    while wait < 5.0 do
        wait = wait + coroutine.yield()
    end
    --]]
    --[[ then play sound
    local alarmSound = SoundsManager.getSound("sounds/alarm.ogg")
    alarmSound:play()
    while alarmSound:isPlaying() do
          coroutine.yield()
    end
    --]]
    print("Event ended")
end
```

FPS.lua

```
local FPS = 
{
   fps = 0,
   lastFPS = 0,
   framesTime = 0.0
}

function FPS.render(frameDelta)
    FPS.fps = FPS.fps + 1
    FPS.framesTime = FPS.framesTime + frameDelta
    if FPS.framesTime >= 1.0 then
       if FPS.fps ~= FPS.lastFPS then
          print("[FPS] ".. FPS.fps)
          FPS.lastFPS = FPS.fps
       end
       FPS.framesTime = 0.0
       FPS.fps = 0
    end    
end

return FPS
```

EventsManager.lua

```
require "event"
local EventsManager = {}

function EventsManager.init()
   EventsManager.event = coroutine.create(event) 
end

function EventsManager.update(frameDelta)
    if coroutine.status(EventsManager.event) ~= 'dead' then
       coroutine.resume(EventsManager.event, frameDelta)
    end
end

return EventsManager
```

Main.lua

```
EventsManager = require "EventsManager"
FPS = require "FPS"

EventsManager.init()

while true do
local frameDelta = getFrameDelta() --getting frameDelta somehow
EventsManager.update(frameDelta)-- comment this and fps will be ok
--render scene 
FPS.render(frameDelta)
end
```

Comment: Perhaps, closures and not coroutines could help you keep the speed. i.e. [Link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2341851/847349)

Comment: Maybe, but i still don't understand why just empty yielding can have such performance impact, even if i call resume every frame.

Comment: I guess, a good place to look would be `ldo.c(554):LUA_API int lua_yieldk`. My _guess_ is that yielding is not trivial, as the coroutine should be safely prepared for resuming. Just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code, only `getFrameDelta` just returns the time gap between the previous and current calls, without any scene to render. Also I changed the wait time to 10 seconds.

```
local prevtime = os.clock()

local getFrameDelta = function()
    local curtime = os.clock()
    local framedelta = curtime - prevtime   
    prevtime = curtime
    return framedelta
end
```

Here's my output:

> D:\Dev>lua5.1 LUAFPS.lua
>   Event started Waiting for .. 10
>
> [FPS] 879171
>   [FPS] 882366 [FPS] 880471 [FPS] 882018 [FPS] 880513 [FPS] 881368 [FPS]
>   879623 [FPS] 881938 [FPS] 880498
>
> Event ended
>
> [FPS] 882053 [FPS]
>   1279909 [FPS] 1279631 [FPS] 1279899 [FPS] 1277089 [FPS] 1278399 [FPS]
>   1279005 [FPS] 1280125

So, yes co-routines do take their toll. Every time a co-routine `yields` it has to keep tab of where the function is left off, so it can `resume` at that point the next time you call it. I assume this accounts for the discrepancy that I see : `800Kfps v 1200Kfps`.

That said, I don't understand why you need `co-routines` for calculating FPS. You already have the code that calculates the FPS in `FPS.render`. It should suffice to just call it after you render your scene, like you are doing now, just skip the event manager part which calls the `co-routine`.

Comment: Thank you for benchmark. I don't use co-routines for calculating FPS, i mean using co-routines impact my FPS much.
Funny part, what even if i lower base FPS by drawing more objects, fps while event active stays 300 - 350, so let it be i think.